# save user data to dynamodb table when creating user using AWS user pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am fairly new to cognito.  I have successfully set up my user sign in with user pools.

I would like to create a dynamodb entry for the user on the server side when they signup with cognito.

Is this possible using the lambda triggers during the sign up workflow?  I am also not very familiar with lambda but if this is possible I would need to access the user attributes when they sign up with cognito and save these to my dynamodb user table.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use a Lambda trigger to add the user to your DynamoDB table. From the Lambda trigger event object, you will retrieve the user attributes that can be saved to the table.

You can use one of the following triggers, based on your requirements,

- [Pre Sign-up Lambda Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup.html)
- [Post-Confirmation Lambda Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-confirmation.html)

Comment: being completely new to user pools and lambda could you provide an example of how to create the lambda function to do that?  I could not find any tutorials for that.